# getting No Directionality widget found error and can't fix it

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having a problem where it shows an error that i don't really understand. I'm trying to input a background image in my app but it doesn't work.

This is my screen.
[image]

and this is my code. (my code is quite long so i cut it. if you want to see my whole code i will post it here)

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MainScreen();
  }
}

class MainScreen extends State<MyApp> {
  final currentTime = DateTime.now();
  final busStopController = TextEditingController();

  //To customise the greeting according to the time
  String greeting() {
    var hour = DateTime.now().hour;
    if (hour < 12) {
      return 'Morning';
    }
    if (hour < 17) {
      return 'Afternoon';
    }
    return 'Evening';
  }

  //Strings for user input and busStop
  String name = '';
  String busStop = '';

  //Strings for different bus timings
  String sb1timing = '';
  String sb2timing = '';
  String sb3timing = '';
  String sb4timing = '';

  //Different icon colors for bus capacity
  Color _iconColorDefault1 = Colors.white;
  Color _iconColorDefault2 = Colors.white;
  Color _iconColorDefault3 = Colors.white;
  Color _iconColorDefault4 = Colors.white;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Builder(builder: (context) {
      return Stack(children: [
        const Backgroundimage(),
        Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          drawer: Drawer(
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: [
                const DrawerHeader(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black45,
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Directionality` widget is used in widgets that set text direction in the `Text` widgets inside the Flutter widget tree.

By default, it's set inside the `MaterialApp` of your flutter project, and in your code, there is no `MaterialApp`, which will lead to the error.

so wrapping `MainScreen()` will a `Directionality` will fix your error, but I recommend always having a `MaterialApp` since this kind of error will be thrown with other necessary widgets such as, `Navigator`, `Theme`, `MediaQuery`...

here is what you should do, replace this:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MainScreen();
  }
```

with this:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MaterialApp( // this should be present
    home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
 }
}
```